# Why can't I see any suggestion in PhpStorm?

Tags: templates, phpstorm

I downloaded .jar file for PhpStorm Templates for quick code. I imported it using `File->Import Setting` without any error, I can also see all templates in `Setting->Live Templates`, but it doesn't suggest me those imported templates...

[image]

Comment: Where do you try to use them? What do you press to get them etc?

Comment: i press 2magento.... to get suggestion.....

Comment: 1) Press `Ctrl + J` (or whatever shortcut you may have there for `Code | Insert Live Template...` and see if they will appear in the list there 2) The biggest issue that I see right now with those Live Templates ... that they use space in their abbreviations... as it's a word delimiter. Abbreviation better be 1 "solid" word (use some delimiters like `_-:` if needed) and Description field used to describe what it does. Even stuff like `magento:eav` (the `:` symbol there) will cause certain issues. With spaces in abbreviation the `Ctrl+J` must be the only way of inserting them.